# Keil uVision debugging step through code outside project

Tags: c, debugging, keil, jtag, step-through

I loaded some code into RAM dynamically and I'm trying to debug it. When stepping through code in uVision it always skips over all the code that is not in the current project and stops at the first instruction that did come from the current project. This results in it also skipping over my dynamically loaded and linked code.

Is there a way to stop uVision from skipping over code that does not come from the currently opened project? I would like to step through the instructions that have just been loaded into RAM.

Thanks in advance, any attention is appreciated.

Comment: maybe instruction level debugging. It skips if does not have any debug & source code info.

Comment: Maybe you can set a breakpoint inside the dynamically loaded code after loading it.

Answer (score 0):

You may wish to use the Disassembly Window (**View — Disassembly Window**) to step through the assembly instructions on RAM. Put a break point where your RAM code is about to be called, e.g. at your function pointer, then click on the Disassembly Window and then Step in this window, one assembly instruction at a time.

Further descriptions of the window can be found [here](http://www.keil.com/support/man/docs/uv4/uv4_db_dbg_disasmwin.htm)